# Next.js error on iPhone iOS 15 appears when opening the site

Tags: reactjs

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7iFe.jpg)

On a project with a React/NextJS stack, everything builds and runs normally, it works well on all devices except iOS up to version 15, there this error occurs (in the screenshot).

I tried to downgrade the next version, tried to clean the npm cache, remove package_lock.json and node_modules and .next build folder and reset, but nothing helped

Comment: Hi, @dragosdev, can you edit your question to add the error message as text, so your question can be understood without relying on an image? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors